# toggleClass() on Parent not working even though the parent is being found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have the following HTML repeated in my page (obviously the names, for and id attributes change in each instance):

```
<div class="funkyCheckBox">
<label for="uniqueName"> Whatever Text </label>
<input type="checkbox"  name="uniqueName" id="uniqueName" />
</div>
```

What this does with some CSS is make the give the appearance of a big button, the input is hidden and I add a class to the div depending on the checked value of the input. I use the following JavaScript /jQuery for this

```
$(".funkyCheckBox").live("click, tap", function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass("funkyCheckBoxActive");
    var nextCheckBox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
    nextCheckBox.prop("checked", !nextCheckBox.prop("checked"));
});
```

Now this was all fine and good but during testing I noticed that if you click on the label text the class was not applied and the value of the input isn't toggled... thus I added the following...

```
$(".funkyCheckBox label").live("click, tap", function(event){                  
    $(this).parent("div").toggleClass("funkyCheckBoxActive");
    var nextCheckBox = $(this).next("input[type=checkbox]");
    nextCheckBox.prop("checked", !nextCheckBox.prop("checked"));
});
```

Now this is great as clicking the label text now changes the value of the input however the parent DIV is not taking / toggling the "funkyCheckBoxActive" class. I am unsure why is as I then used `console.log($(this).parent("div"))` within the callback function and I am outputting the attributes of th dom object. Does anyone know why my `toggleClass` is not being applied?

Comment: Could you not put it back to how it was and add the label->click block with `$(this).parent("div").click()` inside?

Comment: If I try that the checkbox is not responsive???

Comment: What makes you think class isn't being changed? It likely is.  If issue is you aren't seeing visual CSS changes, it's likely a CSS specificity issue. After `toggleClass` try `console.log( $(this).closest('.funkyCheckBoxActive').length)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery, your code will work or not.
Note that the browser is already toggling the checkbox when you click on a label that references it; so you would only need to do this:

```
$('#uniqueName').change(function() {
    $(this).parents("div").toggleClass("funkyCheckBoxActive");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

please use the "on" method instead of "live" as it is deprecated. also the "for" attribute in LABEL Tag points to an existing Id.

here is the corrected and working code:

```
<div class="funkyCheckBox">
    <label for="uniqueName"> Whatever Text </label>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="uniqueName" id="uniqueName" />
</div>
```

and

```
$(".funkyCheckBox label").click(function(event){
     $(this).parent("div").toggleClass("funkyCheckBoxActive");

     var nextCheckBox = $(this).next("input[type=checkbox]");
     var nextCheckBoxValue = nextCheckBox.val();

     nextCheckBox.val(! nextCheckBoxValue);
}); ​
```

​

EDIT: here is the jsFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/RUYWT/

**EDIT2:** @Mike Sav: I have revised your code and it's working now with all possible cases:
http://jsfiddle.net/RUYWT/11/

Comment: 1. Calling people idiots isn't going to get you far in the community. 2. Your code doesn't work, add the class and you will see it isn't applied when clicking the checkbox, http://jsfiddle.net/RUYWT/1/

Comment: Use FireBug and you will see the toggled class on DIV (hopefully)

EDIT: I've updated the jsFiddle in case that you don't know what Firebug is : http://jsfiddle.net/RUYWT/3/